# How to know the moment, when an rxjs Observable gets unsubscribed (cancelled)?

Tags: rxjs, observable

Imagine a situation:
you have a flag, that points that the request is currently processing (`busy`).
If it is - then return null, else - return results from `SomeService`. When the results from the API are returend, or an error occured, the `busy` flag is set to `false`.

The problem is, that while the API call is processing (the flag `busy` is `true` at this moment) and the observable gets unsubscribed (request cancelled) the flag `busy` is not reset back to the `false` value. How this can be fixed?

The `catchError` operator does not work in this case.

somewhere in app:

```
letsCheck().subscribe();
letsCheck().unsubscribe();
```

in a service:

```
busy: boolean;

letsCheck(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.busy) {
        return of(null); // actually this logic is not the important part here, in real scenario there will be a queued requests
    }

    this.busy = true;
    return resultsFromAnAPI().pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.busy => false
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        this.busy => false
        return of(null);
      })
    ); // Observable
}
```

Comment: With newer RxJS versions you can even use `tap({ finalize: () => this.busy = false })`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `finalize` operator. The logic defined in it will be run when the observable completes, errors or when manually unsubscribed.

```
return resultsFromAnAPI().pipe(
  finalize(() => this.busy = false)
);
```

cheers